# Why does this F# computation expression give a warning?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

This code:

```
type Result = Success of string

type Tracer() =
  member x.Bind(p: Result, rest: (string -> Result)) = 
    match p with
    | Success s -> rest s

let tracer = new Tracer()

let t = tracer {
  let! x = Success "yes!"
  let! y = Success "waste of time"
  return! Success x
}

printfn "%A" t
```

prints **Success "yes!"**

But gives a warning that implies that it shouldn't work:

**File1.fs(19,3): warning FS0708: This control construct may only be used if the computation expression builder defines a 'ReturnFrom' method**

Seems like a strange warning: if it's right, then the code shouldn't work.  Is it really just saying that the builder had to synthesize ReturnFrom?

(F# Version 1.9.7.4, compiling for .NET Framework Version v4.0.21006)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sent the question to fsbugs@microsoft.com, and it's a bug.  They said it'll be an error in the next release.

(They responded almost immediately, on Thanksgiving no less - it just took me a while to put the info here.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that this works.  [Section 6.10 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc245030819) doesn't mention anything about synthesizing `ReturnFrom` when it's not specified.  Is there a reason not to just put a `member x.ReturnFrom v = v` on the builder?  Or a `member x.Return(v) = Success v`, so that you could end your `tracer` block with `return x`, which would be more traditional?

Comment: No reason to not do any of those things - this was just some example code I was playing around with, and I couldn't understand what the error was trying to tell me.

I mailed this off to fsbugs, we'll see what they have to say.